# Generate n lists of numbers between two numbers with python

Tags: python, list

I have a tuple **J = (inf, sup, n)** and I want to generate **n** lists of numbers between inf and sup.

```
J = (-7, 9.5, 4)
```

The expected output should be like this:

```
[-7,-2.875], [-2.875,1.25], [1.25,5.375], [5.375,9.5]
```

Can someone help ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sorry but this platform is not for getting code solutions but for debugging or fixing issues in your code. It would help if you could mention what is it have you tried so far ? Here's the logic you could use:

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users. I notice you have used the `numpy` tag for this question. If you are specifically looking for a way to do this with Numpy, then you should explicitly say so, and also show input and output the way that Numpy formats its arrays. At any rate, you should explain more clearly *why* the expected output is what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but this platform is not for getting code solutions but for debugging or fixing issues in your code. It would help if you could mention what is it have you tried so far ?

However, here's a solution.

Your inputs are inf, n, sup.

If you notice, you list of n tuples in between inf and sup.

So the difference will be (sup-inf)/n

In the example you gave, it will be (9.5-(-7))/4 = 4.125.

So we will move from -7 to 9.5 by storing in each tuple, an initial value and a final value.

**For 1st pair**,
initial value = -7
final value = -7+4.125 = -2.875

**For 2nd pair**,
initial = -2.875
Final = -2.875 + 4.125 = 1.25

**3rd pair**,
initial = 1.25
final = 1.25 + 4.125 = 5.375

**4th pair**
initial = 5.375
final = 5.375 + 4.125 = 9.5

You may create a function that returns a list of these Pairs.

```
def getLists(inf, n, sup):
    output = []
    initial = inf
    final = sup
    continuous_difference = (sup-inf)/n

    while(initial != final):
        output.append([initial, initial + continuous_difference])
        initial += continuous_difference
    
    return output

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(getLists(-7, 4, 9.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[J[0] + i/J[2]*(J[1]-J[0]), J[0] + (i+1)/J[2]*(J[1]-J[0])] for i in range(J[2])]
```